# Excel/Access running/cumulative totals for each range based on date

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I am trying to do the following on Excel. I also have the same data on Access. So any help on access is also fine.
I have data in the following format (on excel, using comma here as cell separator ofcourse)

```
Date,Time,Count
Apr-1-2013, 17:00, 21
Apr-1-2013, 17:05, 10
Apr-1-2013, 17:10, 15
.
.
Apr-1-2013, 21:00, 36
Apr-2-2013, 17:00, 10
.
.
Jun-30-2013, 21:00, 20
```

(Basically for all week days between Apr and June, I have a count value for every 5 minute bucket)

I need the cumulative totals for each date range starting from 17:00 till 21:00, again starting fresh from next day at 17:00
Therefore my result would look like this:

```
Date,Time,Cumulative Count
Apr-1-2013, 17:00, 21
Apr-1-2013, 17:05, 31 (21+10)
Apr-1-2013, 17:10, 46 (31+15)
.
.
Apr-1-2013, 21:00, Grand total for Apr-1
Apr-2-2013, 17:00, 10 (Starts fresh again for new ay)
.
.
Jun-30-2013, 21:00, 20
```

Comment: Source data does not include time values < 17:00 and >21:00

Comment: Do you want a solution that would format the result as you posted?
As in it will add a line to the end of a date series indicating the subtotal?

Comment: All,Thanks so far. 1. @ derek - I am NOT looking for formatting . The explanation in brackets was only for guidance 2. I have already tried pivot, but I need the output to upload into a database for further processing and visualization, so pivot does not help as date as a column will be lost. I need date as a column to be preserved.Brute force option is to copy paste into new spreadsheet the results of pivot, but with 60 days thats too long and I need to automate this. 3. I am looking at cumulative Totals for each day's data in ascending time order (starting from 17:00 till 21:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my answer to fit you question better!

This can be done either with a macro, or using a IF statement
I think in this case a formula based solution will be the easiest to implement.

The formula I used:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,C2,C2+D1) simply fill down the formula to get the accumulation!

Date    Time    Count   Accumulate
01-Apr  time    13      13
01-Apr  time    2       15
01-Apr  time    4       19
03-Apr  time    3       3
03-Apr  time    2       5
03-Apr  time    5       10
09-Apr  time    10      10
09-Apr  time    5       15
09-Apr  time    12      27
```

Comment: Both the above are good, but if there was only one date, they would have worked. The excel file has 60 different dates, and 48 time buckets(17:00 til 19:00 in 5 minute intervals) for each date with a count value for each of 60*48 rows. I need to do cumulative total of column 'count' from 17:00 till 19:00 for each date, start over again for next date. If I follow, any of the above, I need to perform the operation for each date. I am looking for a solution that at one shot, fulfils the requirement

Comment: @RatnakarVellanki I've updated the answer to fit your question better!

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be a PivotTable:

[image: SO17840660 example]

*Edit* Amendment in view of comments:

[image: SO17840660 second example]

Comment: I'm starting to think we might've misunderstood the question.
Ratnakar Vellanki might want to format it in a way that it adds a line to the raw data like a subtotal.

Comment: Both the above are good, but if there was only one date, they would have worked. The excel file has 60 different dates, and 48 time buckets(17:00 til 19:00 in 5 minute intervals) for each date with a count value for each of 60*48 rows. I need to do cumulative total of column 'count' from 17:00 till 19:00 for each date, start over again for next date. If I follow, any of the above, I need to perform the operation for each date. I am looking for a solution that at one shot, fulfils the requirement